# Java: JPA classes, refactoring from Date to DateTime

Tags: java, sql, datetime, orm, jpa

With a table created using this SQL

```
Create Table X (
    ID varchar(4) Not Null,
    XDATE date
);
```

and an entity class defined like so

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "X")
public class X implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, length = 4)
    private String id;
    @Column(name = "XDATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date xDate; //java.util.Date
    ...
}
```

With the above, I can use JPA to achieve object relational mapping. However, the `xDate` attribute can only store dates, e.g. `dd/MM/yyyy`.

How do I refactor the above to store a full date object using just one field, i.e. `dd/MM/yyyy HH24:mm`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried changing the `@Temporal` value to `TemporalType.DATETIME`? java.util.Date and java.sql.Date both store date and time components, the TemporalType controls which part JPA stored/pays attention to; date, time, or both.

Comment: @sblundy : Thanks for the answer, that was my gut feel too, however, do I need to change the member variable in my entity class, or the schema definition for the table?

Comment: @bguiz : Field no, column yes. It depends on which DB you're using, but DATETIME should work

Comment: @sblundy : I'm using Toplink / JavaDB

Comment: @bguiz : TIMESTAMP. Here's the relevent manual page http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/dev/ref/ref-single.html#crefsqlj31068

Comment: @sblundy: java.sql.Date does *not* store a time component.

Comment: +1 & check @blundy: Worked like a charm with `java.util.Date`, but as pointed out by @mtpettyp, failed with `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: Odd - I don't see DATETIME as an option, I only see TemporalType.TIME, TemporalType.DATE, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP. I'm using JPA2 w/Eclipselink 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461

Answer (score 7):

If you want to also store time information at the database level, use `TemporalType.DATETIME`:

```
@Column(name = "XDATE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATETIME)
private Date xDate; //java.util.Date
```

Use a `TIMESTAMP` column type at the database level (and `xDate` will be stored as `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S'`).

Comment: +1 @Pascal Thivent : Thanks for the answer, both of you were right,  but I'm giving the check to sblundy since he was first in.

Comment: Hi. I am using JPA with `EclipseLink`, and the `TemporalType` only have option `DATE`, `TIME`, and `TIMESTAMP`, and not `DATETIME`. Should I use `TIMESTAMP` or `TIME`.

Comment: Odd - I don't see DATETIME as an option, I only see TemporalType.TIME, TemporalType.DATE, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP. I'm using JPA2 w/Eclipselink 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461